# react-native dynamically changing view height using ternary operator

Tags: javascript, react-native, ternary-operator

I am trying to dynamically change view height using a ternary operator.

First I get the screen height of the device

```
const {
  height: SCREEN_HEIGHT,
} = Dimensions.get('window')

const IS_IPHONE_X = SCREEN_HEIGHT === 812
const IS_IPHONE_XR = SCREEN_HEIGHT === 896
const IS_IPHONE_SIX = SCREEN_HEIGHT === 667
```

Second, I check if the device is `iphoneX`

```
const IMAGE_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ?( IS_IPHONE_X ? 332 : 368): 0
```

Using a ternary operator is good but I can only check two device with the code above.

Is there a way I could use multiple conditions in a ternary operator? 
I tried this. But gives me an error:

```
const IMAGE_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ?( IS_IPHONE_X ? 332 : IS_IPHONE_XR ? : 368 : IS_IPHONE_SIX : 300) : 0
```

Comment: Yes you can use an arbitrary amount of ternary operators in the same expression, but you need to make sure that it's syntactically correct. The portion after `IS_IPHONE_XR ?` contains errors. The question mark is directly followed by a colon, which is syntactically incorrect (delete that colon). Then the bit with `IS_IPHONE_SIX` is an incorrect / incomplete ternary expression.  I guess you meant to write `IS_IPHONE_SIX ? 300 : 0` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can for sure achieve this with Ternary operator but it is not advised to use nested ternaries. I would suggest to use `if else` here instead of ternary.

```js
  let height = 0;

  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    if (IS_IPHONE_X) {
      height = 332;
    } else if (IS_IPHONE_XR) {
      height = 368;
    } else if (IS_IPHONE_SIX) {
      height = 300;
    }
  }
```

If you want to do this with ternary only then

```js
const height = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? (IS_IPHONE_X ? 332 : (IS_IPHONE_XR ? 368 : (IS_IPHONE_SIX ? 300 : 0))) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use logical operator with ternary operator.

```
const IMAGE_BAR_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? ( IS_IPHONE_X && 332 || IS_IPHONE_XR &&  368 || IS_IPHONE_SIX && 300) : 0
```

Or I recommend split code.

```js
const SCREEN_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

iOSDeviceInfo = () => {
  switch (SCREEN_HEIGHT) {
    case 812:
      return 'X';
    case 866:
      return 'XR';
    case 667:
      return 'SIX';

    default:
      break;
  }  
}


const IMAGE_BAR_HEIGHT = {
  X: 332,
  XR: 368,
  SIX: 300,
}

const imageHeight = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? IMAGE_BAR_HEIGHT[iOSDeviceInfo()] : 0
```

Not tested.